# Re-using the code between 2 different models in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber

I have 2 Models: Article and Category. Article depends on Category: in order to create Article, I have to create Category first. And I have 4 files: `article.features, category.features, article_steps.rb, category_steps.rb`. In somewhere in `article_steps.rb` I have to create Category in order to create Article itself. But the code for creating Category has already been defined in `category_steps.rb`.

How can I re-use it in `article_steps.rb`? I could do that within the same model, but is there any way to do that in different models?

Comment: Can't FactoryGirl handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps defined in `category_steps.rb` can be used in any feature file. Just use the `Given` steps defined in `category_steps.rb` in `article.features`:

**article.features**

```
Feature: Articles
  In order to ...
  As a ...
  I want to ...

Background:
  Given the "Test" Category exists

Scenario: Creating an Article
  When I create an Article with the following attributes:
    | Title        | Body      |
    | Just Testing | Test test |
  And the "Just Testing" Article is in the "Test" Category
  Then an Article should exist with the following attributes:
    | Title        | Body      |
    | Just Testing | Test test |
  And the "Just Testing" Article should be in the "Test" Category
```

Since the "Test" category will be used throughout the scenarios, move the creation of this data into the Scenario `Background`. Next, in your step definition files, define the steps above:

**category_steps.rb**

```
Given /^the "(.*?)" Category exists$/ do |category_name|
  Category.create! :name => category_name
end
```

**article_steps.rb**

```
When /^I create an Article with the following attributes:$/ do |table|
  article = Article.new
  # Loop over the rows and columns to set properties on article
  article.save!
end

When /^the "(.*?)" Article is in the "(.*?)" Category$/ do |article_title, category_name|
  article = Article.find_by_title article_title
  article.category = Category.find_by_name category_name
  article.save!
end

Then /^an Article should exist with the following attributes:$/ do |table|
  expected = Article.new
  # Loop over rows and columns of table to set properties on article
  actual = Article.find_by_title expected.article_title

  # Compare expected and actual for differences
  expect(expected.title).to eq actual.title
  expect(expected.body).to eq actual.body
end

Then /^the "(.*?)" Article should be in the "(.*?)" Category$/ do |article_title, category_name|
  article = Article.find_by_title article_title
  expect(article.category.name).to eq category_name
end
```

The whole idea of step definitions is to promote code reuse between multiple scenarios and feature files. Step definitions aren't supposed to be tied to a feature file. Rather, they should be generic enough to be reused in multiple situations.

Comment: When you're creating an Article, how do you know the category_id?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: I've updated my answer. This should give you a better "big picture" view of how step definitions can be reused between scenarios, and even features.